# Using of Keywords as variable names

Tags: c#, .net

Why does the first line compile and the second not?

```
string var = "123";

var string = "123";
```

I mean `string` and `var` should be both keywords..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`var` is a [contextual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/contextual-keywords), whereas `string` is not.

Contextual keywords are

> used to provide a specific meaning in the code, but it is not a reserved word in C#.

This is why you can use `var` as a variable name.

Presumably, this is for backwards compatibility. If `var` were introduced as a proper keyword, old code that uses `var` as a variable name would break.

Comment: good answer! I was going to answer quite the same, you beat me first :)

Comment: good answer +1 great explnation about the historical background

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#keywords